# Android remove button dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button and when I press it, i want to remove it (not make it invisible). I read that I can do that using `layout.removeView(mybutton)` but what is the layout ? and how can I get it in my activity

```
Button showQuestion;
private void initialize() {
    showQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAnswerQuestionShowQuestion);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bAnswerQuestionShowQuestion:
                showQuestion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //Here i want to delete the button
                question.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                theAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                answerQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showChoices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The layout is the View parenting you Button.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

see [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29)

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) button.getParent();
if(null!=layout) //for safety only  as you are doing onClick
  layout.removeView(button);
```

Comment: the website android developers is forbidden to my country

Comment: the function showQuestion.getParent().revmoveView doesn't exists

Answer (score 15):

> i have a button and when i press it , i want to remove it (not make it
>   invisible)

=> You did as below:

```
 showQuestion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Try with:

```
 showQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

FYI, INVISIBLE just hide the view but physically present there and GONE hide as well remove the presence physically as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
      button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Layout is the parent Layout of your Button, usually a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

You can get it as follows:

```
ViewParent layout = button.getParent();
```